# File API Upload - XMLHttpRequest onload event not firing on larger files

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I'm using the new File API for uploading files to my site. I have everything working as expected. Files are submitted and uploaded successfully.

The only problem I'm finding is that my onload event for the XMLHttpRequest does not fire on files with a larger file size. Any ideas on why this would work most of the time but fail for larger files?

I've tried sticking code in both the XMLHttpRequest and the XMLHttpRequest.upload onload events. Both seem to fail with large files. I'm trying to stay away from the workaround of sniffing for 100% in the progress event to denote completion.

Comment: What web server are you using and what do you consider "large"?  Most have a max upload file size, I think the default for IIS is ~1MB.

Comment: Apache 2 and PHP 5. the file is uploaded successfully so I don't suspect it's a server side issue. The only thing not working is the actual event firing. The event fails to fire on an mp4 file that's 705KB. But fires fine on a 82KB jpeg image.

Comment: the new file api seems to use post to upload files in xhr. try to set a new post size in the php settings.

Comment: Did You manage to resolve this issue? If so it would be nice if You could post Your solution :)