# Page won't alert when XMLHttpRequest is done

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a upload form that shows a status bar while the file uploads using AJAX. When the upload is done i want the user to know but when it is done nothing happens but i tell it to alert "Done."

My code:

```
UploadB.click(function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

                var FInput = $('#Files').val();

                if(FInput != '')
                {
                    var Data = new FormData();

                    var Files = document.getElementById('Files');

                    for(var I = 0; I < Files.files.length; ++I)
                    {
                        var FilesName = Files.files[I].name;

                        Data.append('File[]', Files.files[I]);
                    }
                    var Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    Request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event)
                    {
                        if(event.lengthComputable)
                        {
                            Percent = event.loaded / event.total;
                            Progress = document.getElementById('Progress');
                            Loaded = Math.round(Percent * 100);

                            $('#Progress').progressbar({
                                value: Loaded
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#Progress').text('There Was An Error Getting The Percent');  
                        }
                    });

                    Request.upload.addEventListener('load', function(event)
                    {

                    });

                    Request.upload.addEventListener('error', function(event)
                    {
                        alert('Upload Failed.');
                    });

                    Request.upload.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event)
                    {
                        if(this.readyState == 4)
                        {
                            if(this.status == 200)
                            {
                                alert('Done.');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('There Was An Error, Either Try Again Or Contact Us');
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    Request.open('POST', 'Upload.php');
                    Request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
                    Progress.style.display = 'block';
                    Request.send(Data); 
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Please Select A File / Files');  
                }
            });
```

Comment: Assuming that your request actually works...try moving your readystatechange listener and put it before your code block that opens and sends the data.

Comment: i had that before and then moved it thinking that would worked.

Comment: but it still doesnt work.

Comment: everything works. and the file gets uploaded but it just wont alert

Comment: Does your request work?  And, does the readystatechange execute?  If so, inspect the readyState and status values.

Comment: With `.upload` I believe you want to use `load` as the callback rather than `readystatechange`.  Also, I think that `this` in the callback is `window`, but I could be wrong about that

Comment: How large is the file? The issue described here could be relevant (unfortunately there was no solution posted): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069033/file-api-upload-xmlhttprequest-onload-event-not-firing-on-larger-files

Comment: What's the point of using jQuery to get a few elements by ID, when you're not using it for the hard stuff?

Comment: @MattB. it worked with large files using the answer below.

Comment: @adeneo i'm not sure how to do this with JQuery i'm 14 anyways theres a lot for me to learn i know how to use $.ajax in jquery but not for file uploads, or is it the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the `readystatechange` event only fires on `XMLHttpRequest`, and not on `XMLHttpRequest.upload`.

Try:

```js
Request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
    if(this.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(this.status == 200)
        {
            alert('Done.');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('There Was An Error, Either Try Again Or Contact Us');
        }
    }
});
```